# RactiveJS - How can I remove event handler from a specific element (node)

Tags: events, ractivejs

For example, I have registered a proxy event on an element

```
<a href="javascript:;" on-mouseover="doSomething">Do something</a>
```

Say I have a reference to this element (e.g. from event.node inside the event handler), how can I remove/unsubscribe "doSomething" from just this specific element? (I still want to keep this event for other elements)

Comment: The short answer is that you can't - the `doSomething` handler instead has to be responsible for *not* doing whatever it would otherwise have done. Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve? There may be a better way.

Comment: thank you @RichHarris, it's already answered in here https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/846